# Liouville Theorem analogue in generalized velocities?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, coordinate-systems, phase-space, volume, complex-systems

The Liouville Theorem concerns dynamics in phase space: does an analogue exist in configuration space, and, if not, could you give a motivation / proof why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a direct counterexample to complete Qmechanic's answer.
 Take $L= q \dot{q}^2/2$ for $q>0$. As a consequence
$$p = q\dot{q}$$
and so
$$dp = q d\dot{q} + \dot{q} dq\:.$$
Therefore, the canonical volume in terms of Lagrangian variables is
$$dp\wedge dq = q d\dot{q} \wedge dq\:.$$
Since the left-hand side is preserved by solutions of the equation of motion and $q=q(t)$ is not constant in time along these solutions, it is not possible that 
$$ d\dot{q} \wedge dq$$
is also constant along the motion of the system. So the apparantly natural volume constructed out of Lagrangian variables is not constant in time on the motion of the system, differently from the canonical volume.

Comment: Mille grazie @Valter Moretti. Anyway, in a book I'm reading, it is stated that the Liouville Theorem doesn't hold in _configuration_ space, "unless the $q_i$s are simple cartesian coordinates"...could you offer an insight about that?

Comment: If coordinates are Cartesian then Legendre's transform is trivial and $p_k$ is proportional to $\dot{q}^k$ by means of a common coefficent independent from $k$. So the canonical volume form can be safely  written using $d\dot{q}^k$ in place of $dp_k$ and a constant factor. I am not sure however that this is the only case...

Comment: I think that is sufficient that the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the Legendre map has value $a \neq 0$ constantly...

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in the cotangent bundle phase space $T^{\ast}M$, there is no generally valid [Liouville Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) (where time evolution is divergencefree) in the base configuration space $M$ nor in its tangent bundle $TM$. For starters, the notion of [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) needs a notion of volume, and neither $M$ nor $TM$ is generically equipped with a canonical volume form.